# Android Canvas Drawing - Best To Minimize Draws?

Tags: android, performance, canvas, android-canvas, android-drawable

An android app I'm updating uses Canvas drawing with a runnable (rather than override onDraw) and has changes to the screen approximately twice per second.  With that being the case, I wonder if it's best to attempt to only draw a frame twice per second (or when there's a change) rather than attempting to achieve maximum frames per second.  The main draw would be to save on battery life.

I would just implement and try to test before and after battery life/app usage, but this is difficult to measure accurately as there is so many other things that can skew the results.  So, wondering if anyone knows what the best practice here is?  If you're not developing a video game and don't necessarily need high frame rates, is it best to attempt to reduce the number of draws as low as possible (i.e. low fps), or would the difference be negligible and you shouldn't bother?

**EDIT** Canvas is derived from lockCanvas() and thus can't be hardware accelerated at this time.

Thanks

Comment: With modern Android devices (since ICS) drawing is usually hardware accelerated. For you it means that you can only draw your frame once and then it will be uploaded to GPU as a texture.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev currently the canvas is one returned by lockCanvas() which can't be hardware accelerated.  The level of effort to convert it into a hardware accelerated one is unfortunately too high to take on right now.

Comment: Ah, you should've mentioned that. What are you drawing exactly?

Comment: I can't get into too many details due to confidentiality (enterprise), but it's all simple shapes.  Few thousands of squares at it's simplest level with simple background.  Some textures, but all in all, very simple 2D canvas with simple shapes, just many of them.